# How to spawn a prefab in the position of the mouse cursor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Instantiate(clickPrefab, Input.mousePosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

this is the code what im using. I want to spawn a "1+" in the mousePosition. The Problem is, that the Prefab is not spawning in the correct location. In the scene view its spawning correct in the game view its spawning totaly random...

```
 void scoreButtonOnClick()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    pos.z = 0;
    Instantiate(clickPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    money += dpc;
    scoreText.text = money.ToString("#.##");
}`
```

this is my setup
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fpEj.png

the Problem is now if I click with your code on my button the text is spawning not in the mouse position. Its spawning alwasy in the center.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS9fx.png

Comment: Is your camera transform at the default rotation(Which is 0, 0, 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you convert your mouse position from Screen to World cordinates with:
[Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

Here's a minimal example, the `Creator` script is added to an empty GameObject on the scene. A prefab is manually assigned on the Editor.

```
public class Creator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Instantiate(prefab, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes you have a single Ortographic Camera in your scene.

With this approach, objects don't appear on the game view, only on the scene:

[image: Z problem]

This happens because when converting Screen to World coordinates, Unity takes the Camera Z position. So the prefabs are created right on top of the camera, and are not rendered. You can manually assign a Z value inside the camera range in order to avoid that:

```
Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
pos.z = 0;
Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
```

[image: Z = 0]

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help! The Problem now is, that the "1+" is spawning always in the same position then clicking. And idk why the X cordinates are always -997

Comment: Hi Beko, I've edited the answer with a few more details. If it doesn't work please describe how is your scene setup [

Comment: I edited the thread with the code.

this is my setup
https://i.imgur.com/NOtcITN.png

the Problem is now if I click with your code on my button the text is spawning not in the mouse position. Its spawning alwasy in the center.

https://i.imgur.com/niS3Pzt.png

Comment: What type of object is your "1+"? A `TextMesh` or `UI Text`? The answer above doesn't apply if you're trying to place objects in a `Canvas`.

Comment: Hello,
its a TextMesh.
If I use a normal UI Text, the hole thing is not Spawning in the Canvas.

Comment: Can you attach a print of your Unity Scene, showing the Project hierarchy and the Inspector? I'm not sure where `scoreButtonOnClick` is being called, if you can highlight this object in the Inspector it'd be good.

Comment: That's odd, I've set up a similar scene and the code works unmodified: https://i.imgur.com/5fFEf5X.gif
I suggest you debug each step: print `Input.mousePosition` to make sure it varies accordingly, then print the resulting `pos` vector, then find where does this value turn into 0,0. If there's any script attached to the "1+" object, make sure it doesn't affect the position.

Comment: Here is my print again: https://prnt.sc/xesiy0

I debuged it and the pos is always the same coordinat ;(
and the mousePosition is always another like it should be

and no I dont have any other script

Comment: Are you using a `Perspective` or `Ortographic` camera? In order to do this with a Perspective camera there's a different approach: https://answers.unity.com/questions/566519/camerascreentoworldpoint-in-perspective.html

Comment: Thank you very much :) I changed to Ortographic and now its working!